# Authorization session always ask for user password in helper

Tags: objective-c, authorization

I have an Objective-C application (https://github.com/NBICreator/NBICreator) with a privileged helper tool.

I have a few different privileged tasks the helper will need to perform during one build, and I want to have the user authenticate only once to perform those tasks.

The authorization works, but I can't seem to reuse the session in the helper. The user always have to authenticate for every step, even if I supply the exact same right to the Security Server and use the same **AuthenticationRef**.

I have read the docs and tested the pre-authentication methods in the main app first, and tried printing out (and retaining the auth session in the helper as well). But nothing I've tried have yet to work successfully.

I need som help figuring out why the Security Server feel the need to reauthenticate.

The code on GitHub in the Master Branch is current, and what I'm trying and testing by changing things back and forth. With that code, the user have to authenticate each time I call a helper function, even if I use the same authentication right.

This is what the right looks like in the authorization database:

```
class = rule;
    created = "470329367.933364";
    "default-prompt" =     {
        "" = "NBICreator is trying to start an Imagr workflow.";
    };
    identifier = "com.github.NBICreator";
    modified = "470329367.933364";
    requirement = "identifier \"com.github.NBICreator\" and anchor apple generic and certificate leaf[subject.CN] = \"Mac Developer: Erik Berglund (BXUF2UUW7E)\" and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] /* exists */";
    rule =     (
        "authenticate-admin"
    );
    version = 0;
```

This is where I define the right: https://github.com/NBICreator/NBICreator/blob/master/NBICreator/Helper/NBCHelperAuthorization.m#L36-L43

```
NSStringFromSelector(@selector(authorizeWorkflowImagr:withReply:)) : @{
                             kCommandKeyAuthRightName    : @"com.github.NBICreator.workflowImagr",
                             kCommandKeyAuthRightDefault : @kAuthorizationRuleAuthenticateAsAdmin,
                             kCommandKeyAuthRightDesc    : NSLocalizedString(
                                                                             @"NBICreator is trying to start an Imagr workflow.",
                                                                             @"prompt shown when user is required to authorize to add a user"
                                                                             )
                             },
```

And this is where I check if the user is authenticated:
https://github.com/NBICreator/NBICreator/blob/master/NBICreator/Helper/NBCHelperAuthorization.m#L222-L253

```
+ (NSError *)checkAuthorization:(NSData *)authData command:(SEL)command authRef:(AuthorizationRef)authRef {
#pragma unused(authData)
NSError *           error;
OSStatus            err = 0;

AuthorizationItem   oneRight = { NULL, 0, NULL, 0 };
AuthorizationRights rights   = { 1, &oneRight };

oneRight.name = [@"com.github.NBICreator.workflowImagr" UTF8String];

err = AuthorizationCopyRights(
                              authRef,
                              &rights,
                              NULL,
                              kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed,
                              NULL
                              );

if ( err != errAuthorizationSuccess ) {
    NSString *message = CFBridgingRelease(SecCopyErrorMessageString(err, NULL));
    error = [NSError errorWithDomain:[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName] code:err userInfo:@{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : message }];
}

    return error;
}
```

As you can see there, I'm testing by setting a hardcoded right name to try and resue that right to the Security Server.

I'm stumped right now, and can't seem to find a way forward. Hoping someone here might know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in how I set up the right in the rights database.

I was using the default code from the Apple example [EvenBetterAuthorizationExample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) for creating and using the rights. But that only points to [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Policy_Database_Constants) for the different rights to use.

None of those were helping me with authenticatin once and the having the helper be authenticated the next time I request authentication for the same right.

After some digging and looking into the actual rules in the authorization database I found a way to copy the rule that AuthenticateWithPrivileges uses, that works by authenticating for 5 minutes until requiring re-authentication.

So, I changed my code for creating my custom right from this:

```
NSStringFromSelector(@selector(addUsersToVolumeAtPath:userShortName:userPassword:authorization:withReply:)) : @{
                             kCommandKeyAuthRightName    : NBCAuthorizationRightAddUsers,
                             kCommandKeyAuthRightDefault : @kAuthorizationRuleAuthenticateAsAdmin,
                             kCommandKeyAuthRightDesc    : NSLocalizedString(
                                                                             @"NBICreator is trying to add a user.",
                                                                             @"prompt shown when user is required to authorize to add a user"
                                                                             )
                             },
```

To this:

```
NSStringFromSelector(@selector(addUsersToVolumeAtPath:userShortName:userPassword:authorization:withReply:)) : @{
                             kCommandKeyAuthRightName    : NBCAuthorizationRightAddUsers,
                             kCommandKeyAuthRightDefault : @{
                                     @"class": @"user",
                                     @"group": @"admin",
                                     @"timeout": @(300),
                                     @"version": @(1),
                                     },
                             kCommandKeyAuthRightDesc    : NSLocalizedString(
                                                                             @"NBICreator is trying to add a user.",
                                                                             @"prompt shown when user is required to authorize to add a user"
                                                                             )
                             },
```

So, instead of using **@kAuthorizationRuleAuthenticateAsAdmin** as the RightDefault, i passed in this dict:

```
@{
    @"class": @"user",
    @"group": @"admin",
    @"timeout": @(300),
    @"version": @(1),
},
```

After that, my helper can request authorization from the user, and then I can reuse that session for the same right during 5 minutes without asking the user again.